# IBM Watson Conversation Service: Jump Backwards

Tags: watson-conversation, watson

I'm using IBM Watson Conversation service, and I was wondering if there is a possibility to jump backwards (one step) to the previous node in the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can [define a `jump to` in the response](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-build.html#responses). As part of that you have to identify the target node. It needs to exist which is true for a previous or parent node.

If you want to jump back to a previous step in the dialog, you could do that programatically. You need to save the context object (in a buffer / stack) and later pass it back with the [message API request](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?curl#send_message).

Comment: I am familiar with the jump to option. But I don't want to identify a target node specifically, instead I just want to go backward in the dialog (So the previous node is not necessarily the parent node but can be any node in the dialog which was reached by the previous step of the dialog).

Comment: I added an option for that. I believe you can only do that programatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: If the need is to keep information from the state before going to the previous node, instead of loading the previous context, you can replace only the context.system. This way the flow position will restart, but not the context.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the jump-to you can specify any node.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSyiY.jpg)

Basically, you need to create a node with the condition where it needs to go back, and then change it to "jump-to" instead of "waiting for user input" and then select the target node.

Edit: Didn't see that data_henrik had already responded